# Error when creating Picturebox at Runtime - Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, debian

I'm new on Mono development, but I could do it before. Last year I tried to run the same project and worked, but now it gives the follow error when I try to create a picturebox at runtime (this "Erro X100" was me who added):

[image: Dialog]

That is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

(...)

MarkArray[y] = new PictureBox();
var _with1 = MarkArray[y];
_with1.Tag = "mark";
_with1.Size = new Size(22, 45);
_with1.Location = new Point(pos_left - 22, pos_top - 45);
_with1.Parent = PictureBox_Map;
_with1.Visible = true;
_with1.BringToFront();
_with1.Image = new Bitmap(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "imagens/mark_icons/bk" + bicicletas_qtd.ToString() + ".gif");
_with1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

I'm using .NET Framwork 2.0 (I tried 4.0 but it gives the same error). The folder "imagens" is at the same dir. It works perfectly on Windows, and as I said before, was working last year in other distro. I remember I updated "Xamarim Studio". Does anyone know how can I solve this problem? Thanks since now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDI+ can't find the file, it is a zero byte file, or doesn't match a file type that it can display.

If it is related to not being able to find the file, check to see which directory `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` is actually pointing to.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was really a problem about directory. Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() returns another path, not where the executable was. I added the folder with those images and it worked fine.

Comment: Glad to be able to help!